# Quandl API returns HTML response on Google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, quandl

API request to quandl for fetching stock data returning HTML response instead of JSON. Its correctly returning JSON result in postman.

```
var url ='https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BSE/BOM'+532540+'?start_date='+startDate+'&end_date='+endDate+'&collapse=weekly&api_key=myapikey'
  console.log(url)
  var options =
      {
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        "contentType" : "application/json",
      };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(response)
```

did anyone have a workaround?

Comment: What's the response?

Comment: actually the response is correct and json data is there.
but not in json format but in html form tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Xml response instead of JSON response from quandl api

#### Solution:

- Explicitly mention the format in the url as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.quandl.com/docs/quick-start-examples-1)

  ```
  GET https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/{database_code}/{dataset_code}/data.{return_format}


  var url ='https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BSE/BOM'+532540+'.json?start_date='+startDate+'&end_date='+endDate+'&collapse=weekly&api_key=myapikey'
  ```

AND/OR

- Try mentioning that you only accept json response in the request using `Accept` header.

```
  var options =
      {
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        "contentType" : "application/json",
        "headers":{"Accept":"application/json"}
      };
```

Comment: That works fine.
here whats the difference between `"contentType" : "application/json"` and 
        `"headers":{"Accept":"application/json"}` ?
I think both specifed the result type

Comment: @Ameer The former specifies the type of content you're **sending**, while the latter specifies the type of content you're able to **accept/receive**. The former is actually not needed in this case as you aren't sending any data(except as query parameters, which if sent as post, it should be **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and not json)